# What is the correct way to make a Create page for products that share a base class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Lets say I have a base class as follows:

```cs
public class Product {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

And I have some classes that inherit this base class:

```cs
 public class SomeProduct: Product {

        public string Type { get; set; }

    }
 public class SomeOtherProduct: Product {

        public string Model { get; set; }

    }
```

What is the correct way to make a create form for creating each of these products? Making different controllers and create pages for each one seems redundant. What is the correct way?

Comment: but they are different aren't they? The create form for `SomeProduct` will be similar to `SomeOtherProduct`, but not the same.

Comment: They are different indeed, I was just wondering if there is a better practice for such task.

Comment: Perhaps a simple factory would be appropriate for your application.  Maybe something like `var product = ProductFactory.Create("productType");`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic base controller:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public abstract class BaseProductController<TProduct, TProductModel> : Controller
    where TProduct : Product, new()
    where TProductModel : ProductModel, new()
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    protected readonly IMapper _mapper;

    protected BaseProductController(ApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet("create")]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new ProductModel());
    }

    [HttpPost("create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(TProductModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        var product = _mapper.Map<TProduct>(model);

        _context.Add(product);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Then, for each type of product:

```
public class SomeProductController : BaseProductController<SomeProduct, SomeProductModel>
{
    public SomeProductController(ApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
        : base(context, mapper)
    {
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I'm assuming view models, because you *are* using view models aren't you? Seriously, though, there's a multitude of reasons to use a view model, especially for handling posts. Here, I'm assuming you're probably going to create a base product view model as well. You could just as easily use a simple `class` constraint instead, if you want to allow any type of class.
- For the base controller, I used `IMapper` from AutoMapper. You can handle mapping in a different way, with a different library, or even manually if you prefer. However, the abstraction provided by a mapping library like AutoMapper, makes this work so much easier.
- When there's inevitably differences that need to be accounted for, you can handle that with hooks. For example you can create a method on the base controller like:

  ```
  public virtual Task BeforeSaveAsync(TProduct product, TProductModel model) =>
      Task.CompletedTask;
  ```

  And then call this in your `Create` post action right before the call to `SaveChangesAsync`. Then, in your derived controllers, you can override this method to perform whatever additional logic you might require. Basically, this lets you stub in functionality without having to redo the entire action. You can implement as many of these types of hooks as you need or desire. For example, you may want to allow something to be done before validation, after save, before the view is returned etc. Or, you might even want to have things like `BeforeCreateAsync` and `BeforeUpdateAsync` to implement different functionality in each action. It's entirely up to you.